# Data loss after reload page (nuxt)

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

My data doesn't appear on screen after reload page, but I have it on my store. With what it can be related.

Before reload
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lL7nr.png)

After reload
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJtQQ.png)

```js
async asyncData({ store, route, error }) {
    try {
      store.commit("order/clearOrder");
      await store.dispatch("order/getOrderServiceBySlug", {
        slug: route.params.id,
        params: {
          include: "category"
        }
      });
      return {};
    } catch (e) {
      const statusCode = e && e.statusCode ? e.statusCode : 404;
      error({ statusCode });
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: can you share some code?

Comment: Of course it doesn't, when you reload the page vuex reloades too. If you want to keep data between sessions, you can store it in localstorage.
Look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persistedstate for example

Comment: I know it. I use asyncData in component, where call an action

Comment: I found that my asyncData is working, but mounted hook is not